# Is it possible to do a sneak attack?

Tags: ni-no-kuni-2-revenant-kingdom

As most rpg games with an "open world" like ni no kuni, you usually can trigger a sneak attack if you engage a monster from behind to gain some kind of advantage. I have tried to do so but it didn't work. On the other hand I've been engaged by a monster while he was chasing me and it did trigger a sneak attack for the ennemies resulting in me starting the fight the wrong way. Which by the way is not that much of a disadvantage. **Is it a feature that will be available later in the game ?**

Spoiler :

> I just signed the treaty with the dog king (can't recall his name).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there isn't any advantage you can gain by touching enemies from behind on the overworld map.